# How can I implement a chrome like "auto-hide navigation" for my Android app?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-gesture

In Chrome, the address bar will be hidden/shown when user swipes up/down the content.

Can I implement the similar logic to my app?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity"
     tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
         <WebView
         android:id="@+id/my_webview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I wonder if there is anything I can do by the following code, so that the ActionBar will be hidden/shown when user swipe up/down the webView.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            webView.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need layout with **alignParentBottom** and **match_parent** WebView and some bar at top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you need code:

1) Declare and set some internal values and **resize** WebView to make it **below** our bar:

```
private int baseHeight;
private int webViewOnTouchHeight;
private int barHeight;
private float heightChange;
private float startEventY;

barHeight = actionBar.getMeasuredHeight();
baseHeight = getView().getMeasuredHeight();
webView.getLayoutParams().height = webView.getMeasuredHeight() - barHeight;
webView.requestLayout();
webView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

2) Create resize method. Here we check new height with limits of screen top and bar height

```
private boolean resizeView(float delta) {
    heightChange = delta;
    int newHeight = (int)(webViewOnTouchHeight - delta);
    if (newHeight > baseHeight){ // scroll over top
        if (webView.getLayoutParams().height < baseHeight){
            webView.getLayoutParams().height = baseHeight;
            webView.requestLayout();
            return true;
        }       
    }else if (newHeight < baseHeight - barHeight){ // scroll below bar
        if (webView.getLayoutParams().height > baseHeight - barHeight){
            webView.getLayoutParams().height = baseHeight - barHeight;
            webView.requestLayout();
            return true;
        }
    } else { // scroll between top and bar
        webView.getLayoutParams().height = (int)(webViewOnTouchHeight - delta);
        webView.requestLayout();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

3) Create custom onTouch listener where we will **resize** WebView and **change Y-value** of our bar

```
private OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startEventY = event.getY();
            heightChange = 0;
            webViewOnTouchHeight = webView.getLayoutParams().height;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float delta = (event.getY()+heightChange)-startEventY;
            boolean heigthChanged = resizeView(delta);
            if (heigthChanged){
                actionBar.setTranslationY(baseHeight - webView.getLayoutParams().height - barHeight);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is work for small "mobile" site, but too lag on big sites, i'm still work under best solution.

Answer (score 5):

This pattern is called Quick Return.
Start with this [blog post](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/08/an-emerging-ui-pattern-quick-return.html).

However, it is worthwhile reading [this](https://plus.google.com/104844169030193199790/posts/fKEeU4xvKvS) when considering its use.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a really clean way to accomplish this without writing any Java code using the Design Support Library. See Dhir Pratap's answer below:

(I would have placed this as a comment but I don't have enough rep.)

[How to Hide ActionBar/Toolbar While Scrolling Down in Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770530/how-to-hide-actionbar-toolbar-while-scrolling-down-in-webview)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You have the right instinct: A comment would have been one appropriate way to point to a helpful answer on another question. Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Answer (score -2):

try the following code, hope it works for you:

```
    private void init(){
    WebView web = new WebView(this);
    final Context context = this;
    web.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // show action bar
                ((Activity) context).getActionBar().show();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // hide action bar
                ((Activity) context).getActionBar().hide();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `ACTION_DOWN` refers to when the user’s finger touches down on the display. As such, this code will quickly show then hide the action bar for every touch.