# How to auto hide toolbar in webview fragments

Tags: android, webview, android-toolbar

I am trying to auto hide toolbar when content is scroll down in webview. For this i have already tried `NestedScrollView`, but it cause height issues in webview, and google does not recommend to use `NestedScrollView` in webivew. I also can't use `Android-ObservableScrollView` because i am already using some custom libs in webview.

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!!!

[How to Hide ActionBar/Toolbar While Scrolling Down in Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770530/how-to-hide-actionbar-toolbar-while-scrolling-down-in-webview)

Followed the second answer and it did the trick.